# What does 'Python executable' mean?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I'm writting something about 'sys.prefix', related with **PEP405**.
What does 'Python executable' mean in this [specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/#specification)?

> This PEP proposes to add a new first step to this search. If a pyvenv.cfg file is found either adjacent to the **Python executable** or one directory above it (if the executable is a symlink, it is not dereferenced), this file is scanned for lines of the form key = value . ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Python executable" in Python documentation and specifications is either the `python` binary itself or a symlink to the binary. The exception is [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable), which always returns the executable that was used to invoke the interpreter even though the documentation states "executable binary".

Answer (score 1):

It just means a python script which you can call in some manner. That pyvenv is a virtual environment created by python.

Comment: It is not necessary to be the file that can be used to invoke python compiler,isn't it?